# is there a way to combine multiple columns with comma separated

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with 1 million+ records and I am looking to combine two columns to one row with a separator, anyone help me how to do it ?

```
def chunk_results(df): 
    n =0
    for i in range(len(df)):
        data_frame = df.iloc[n:n+5]
       # code for combie
      n=n+5

My Dataframe:
 ID   Value
 1     a
 2     b
 3     c
 4     d
 5     e
 6     f 
 7     g
 8     h
 9     i
 10     j
  ........
  ........
  ........
 999,995  xxv
 999,996  xxw
 999,997  xxx
 999,998  xxy
 999,999  xxz
```

,and I need something like this

```
 ID           Value
 1,2,3,4,5     a,b,c,d,e
 6,7,8,9,10    f,g,h,i,j 
  ........
  ........
  ........
 999,995, 999,996, 999,997, 999,998, 999,999  xxv, xxw, xxx, xxy, xxz
```

I am passing chunksize data already into this function chunk_results
as these df[values] is a value to one of the request to API so I want to send it as http://api.com?value=a,b,c,d,e so that I can post multiple values at once, I dont want to post one request at once where I have network latency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) whatever the rows you want and just aggregate them

```
chunksize = 5
df.astype(str).groupby(df.index // chunksize).agg(','.join)
```

**Output**

```
    ID          Value
0   1,2,3,4,5   a,b,c,d,e
1   6,7,8,9,10  f,g,h,i,j
```